Problem related to distribution function of $X\sim \operatorname{Gam}(n,\lambda)$ and the incomplete gamma function
Let $X\sim \operatorname{Gam}(n,\lambda)$. Show that the the distribution function of $X$ is
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!} & \text{if $x>0$},\\
0 & \text{if $x\le 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$
I'm stuck with this problem, don't know how to get the exact same expression as in the definition of $F(x)$ given by the problem. So I did this:
For $\lambda>0$ and $n>0$, the density function of $X$ is
$$f(x)=\frac{\lambda^nx^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(n)}I_{(0,\infty)}(x).$$
The way we obtain the distribution function of a continuous variable is through the equation $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(u)du$, so let
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^nu^{n-1}e^{-\lambda u}}{\Gamma(n)}du=\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{x}u^{n-1}e^{-\lambda u}du.$$
Let us consider $v=\lambda u\Rightarrow dv=\lambda du\Rightarrow dv/\lambda=du$ and if $u=0\Rightarrow v=\lambda(0)$, if $u=x\Rightarrow v=\lambda x$:
$$\int_{0}^{\lambda x}\bigg(\frac{v}{\lambda}\bigg)^{n-1}e^{-v}\frac{dv}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda^n}\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1}e^{-v}dv.$$
Now, observe that this last integral is related to the definition of the gamma function
$$F(x)=\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\frac{1}{\lambda^n}\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1}e^{-v}dv=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1}e^{-v}dv=\frac{\gamma(\lambda x)}{\Gamma(n)}.$$
The function $$\gamma(\lambda x)=\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1}e^{-v}dv$$
is called the incomplete gamma function. Now, in terms of the variables used, let us recall that the Taylor expansion for $e^v$ is given by
$$e^v=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^k}{k!}.$$
Therefore
$$\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-v)^k}{k!}dv=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int_{0}^{\lambda x}v^{n-1+k}dv=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\bigg(\frac{v^{n+k}}{n+k}\bigg)\bigg|_{0}^{\lambda x}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\bigg(\frac{v^{n+k}}{n+k}\bigg)\bigg|_{0}^{\lambda x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\bigg(\frac{(\lambda x)^{n+k}}{n+k}\bigg)=(\lambda x)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(\lambda x)^{k}}{(n+k)k!}.$$
From this step here, I ended up to the point I started, with the incomplete gamma function.

Hint: the expression of the cumulative distribution function of a gamma distribution of parameters $(n,\lambda)$ can be checked by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, this is a direct computation.
Now, suppose that the expression is true for $n$ and let us show for $n+1$. As your computations showed, you will end up with
$$
\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{\Gamma(n+1)}\int_{0}^{x}u^{n+1-1}e^{-\lambda u}du.
$$
Do an integration by parts: integrate $e^{-\lambda u}$ and differentiate $u^{n+1-1}$ in order to lower the degree and get the cdf of a $\Gamma(n,\lambda)$ distribution.
